# How to make UITextField with combination of password-dot and normal text in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Currently my text field is taking input as "111-11-1111" in UITextField. Requirement is to make input as "•••-••-1111". Is this possible to do with the combination of secure text entry and normal text or any other way to accomplish it.

Comment: If this really is a password, why are you storing any part of it as raw text, let alone revealing any part of it? That's puts your users at a severe security risk. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for you opinion but its not password. Its ssn so only thing we need to reveal is last 4 digit.

Comment: Ah okay, I was worried there for a second

Comment: @Alexander Do you have any idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this.

declare a variable as textCount

```
 var textCount = 0
 var originalString = String()
```

Then override the function func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool as below:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string == "" {
        textCount = textCount - 1

        var truncated = textField.text?.substring(to: (textField.text?.index(before: (textField.text?.endIndex)!))!)
        textField.text = truncated
        if textCount == 5 || textCount == 3 {
            let truncated = textField.text?.substring(to: (textField.text?.index(before: (textField.text?.endIndex)!))!)
            textField.text = truncated
        }
        truncated = originalString.substring(to: originalString.index(before: originalString.endIndex))
        originalString = truncated!

    }
    else if textCount < 9 {
        if textCount == 3 || textCount == 5 {
            textField.text = textField.text! + "-"
        }

        if textCount <= 4 {
            textField.text = textField.text! + "*"
            originalString.append(string)
        }
        else {
            textField.text = textField.text! + string
            originalString.append(string)
        }

        textCount = textCount + 1
    }
    print(originalString)

    return false
}
```

Remember to store the text of textfield in delegate itself. Otherwise it will give you wrong value.

Comment: Thanks man. But original data will be replaced by * how can get that data which user actually entered.

Comment: Thanks rahul. I am getting the original value but now backspace is not working on it and i want this filed max length to be 11 with "-" meaning after 2nd dash only 4 digit can be typed.

Comment: Edited . Please check

Comment: Rahul slightly change in previous requirement. I am tweaking up with your code but can you try this. I will be very thankful to you. - ***-**-1234 >> when user starts typing, first 5 charsshown as it is...once 6th entered, first 5 are shown as stars and then 6,7,8,9th one are shwon in clear form

Answer (score 2):

You have to check every text entry in the text field by using

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

this method. And after some particular number of entry, you have append - in your password.